# Algorithm (on java/kotlin) that finds the most matching text blocks

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Suppose I has 4 blocks of text:

```
1.

Premium 95 950,034
950,03
158,34
NUMERAR: 1
REST



2.

Premium 15 950,034
111,03 aaaaa
158,34
NUMERAR: 1
REST


3.

Premium 95 950,034
950,03 bbbbb
158,34
dddddd
fffff


4.

PremiR 95 950,034
950,03
158,34
NUMERAR: 1
REST A
```

As you can see these blocks are different from each other.
There are those that most coincide - this is block **1 and 4**. There are blocks that least match - this is block **2 and 3**.

Is there an algorithm (on java/kotlin) that finds the most matching text blocks? In this example : **1 and 4**

How many words matches in every block?

?

P.S. Maybe Levenshtein Distance can help

Comment: Start by defining the criteria of what "most matching" actually means. It might seem obvious to the human eye, but that doesn't necessarily translate to a program.

Comment: these 4 blocks look like potential objects you can make, then you can just compare each value of each object with the other.

Comment: @a_local_nobody I need algorithm that find most matches. E.e how many words matches in every block?

Answer (score 2):

You should search for [**correlation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_clustering).

The following is not primarily for correlations.
One straight-forward step-wise approach to simplify the data:

Convert every block to a sequence of words; word IDs. And use the [levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to measure the difference between every two sequences.

- Slow, quadratic O(N²).
- Does not respect structured data (title, number X, number Y)
- This does not respect similar words Premium/PremiR.

You could index the blocks by n-grams, subsequences of say n=3 words, thus reducing the number or combinations.